# Referencing a service from another docker-compose file in volumes_from

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Since our docker-compose configuration is quite huge, we want to separate it into multiple files.
Each file defines one part of our application (databases, backend, workers, ...) and should be able to be stopped and started at will (exception: databases need to run first - other containers link to them and depend on them).

However, we also have a media service, which creates and persists the docker volumes that we need for storing the database, ...

#### docker-compose.database.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  media:
    build: ./docker/app_data
    env_file: ./envs/.${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}
    volumes:
      - /data/db
      - /data/files
      - /data/mydb
      - /logs
    command: /bin/true
    networks:
      - my-net

  (...)

  memcached:
    extends:
      file: common-services.yml
      service: memcached
    env_file: ./envs/.${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}
    restart: on-failure
    mem_limit: 4g
    command: memcached -m 3072m -vv
    ports:
      - "11211:11211"
    networks:
      - my-net
```

#### docker-compose.app.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    extends:
      file: common-services.yml
      service: app
    env_file: ./envs/.${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}
    restart: on-failure
    command: "/wait-for-it.sh postgres:5432 -- /entrypoint.sh"
    external_links:
      - myproj_mongo_1:mongo
      - myproj_rabbitmq_1:rabbitmq
      - myproj_memcached_1:memcached
      - myproj_postgres_1:postgres
    volumes_from:
      - media
      - fe
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - my-net

 fe:
    extends:
      file: common-services.yml
      service: fe
    env_file: ./envs/.${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}
    command: npm run build
    networks:
      - my-net
```

Whenever I am trying to use the docker-compose.app.yml configuration with docker-compose to do anything (start, exec, ...), docker-compose exists with the following error:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.app.yml up -d --remove-orphans
ERROR: Service "app" mounts volumes from "media", which is not the name of a service or container.
```

The question now is: how to load the volumes from media properly? The only idea I had (but wanted to avoid, if there is a better solution, since I would have to change a lot of scripts) is to define media in another docker-compose.yml file that is always loaded together with the other docker-compose.yml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this is how I solved it (basically, I gave in to complicated file management, since docker-compose did not support anything else that helped me):

1) Split the services into logical parts, e.g. docker-compose.database.yml
2) Throw the media service into another file: docker-compose.media.yml
3) create scripts that basically replace the docker-compose command with an augmented version that also loads docker-compose.media.yml

We also augmented this further and added lookups in the script for specialized variants (e.g. clean away SFTP containers in order to recreate them on startup, loading all changes in the public key registry or properly shutting down all databases)
We also look up environment-specific files in the same way (e.g. set special settings for specific servers):

Below our examples for run & stop:

**docker_run.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
PWD_DIR=$(pwd)
SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"
cd ${SCRIPT_DIR}
cd ..

SERVER_COMPONENT=$1
export ENVIRONMENT_NAME=$2

if [ ! -f docker-compose.${SERVER_COMPONENT}."${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}".yml ]; then
    ENVIRONMENT_FILE=""
else
    ENVIRONMENT_FILE="-f docker-compose.${SERVER_COMPONENT}."${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}".yml"
fi
if [ ! -f docker-compose.media."${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}".yml ]; then
    MEDIA_ENVIRONMENT_FILE=""
else
    MEDIA_ENVIRONMENT_FILE="-f docker-compose.media."${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}".yml"
fi
docker-compose -f docker-compose.media.yml ${MEDIA_ENVIRONMENT_FILE} -f docker-compose."${SERVER_COMPONENT}".yml ${ENVIRONMENT_FILE} stop
docker-compose -f docker-compose.media.yml ${MEDIA_ENVIRONMENT_FILE} -f docker-compose."${SERVER_COMPONENT}".yml ${ENVIRONMENT_FILE} up -d

cd ${PWD_DIR}
```

**docker_stop.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
PWD_DIR=$(pwd)
SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"
cd ${SCRIPT_DIR}
cd ..

SERVER_COMPONENT=$1
export ENVIRONMENT_NAME=$2
if [ ! -f docker-compose.${SERVER_COMPONENT}."${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}".yml ]; then
    ENVIRONMENT_FILE=""
else
    ENVIRONMENT_FILE="-f docker-compose.${SERVER_COMPONENT}."${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}".yml"
fi
if [ ! -f docker-compose.media."${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}".yml ]; then
    MEDIA_ENVIRONMENT_FILE=""
else
    MEDIA_ENVIRONMENT_FILE="-f docker-compose.media."${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}".yml"
fi
if [ ! -f bin/docker_stop."${SERVER_COMPONENT}".sh ]; then
    # no special docker stio handling
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.media.yml ${MEDIA_ENVIRONMENT_FILE} -f docker-compose."${SERVER_COMPONENT}".yml ${ENVIRONMENT_FILE} stop
else
    bin/docker_stop."${SERVER_COMPONENT}".sh ${SERVER_COMPONENT} ${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}
fi

cd ${PWD_DIR}
```

This is our media file:

**docker-compose.media.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  media:
    build: ./docker/app_data
    env_file: ./envs/.${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}
    volumes:
      - /data/db
      - /data/files
      - /data/postgresdb
      - /logs
    command: /bin/true
    networks:
      - my-net

networks:
  my-net:
```

Here is an example for my development postgres server configuration:

**docker-compose.database.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  (...)

  postgres:
    extends:
      file: common-3rdParty-services.yml
      service: postgres
    env_file: ./envs/.${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}
    restart: on-failure
    volumes_from:
      - media
    environment:
      PGDATA: /data/postgresdb
```

Which overrides with a file like this:

**docker-compose.database.tst.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  (...)

  postgres:
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Customising stop script actions:

**docker_stop.database.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
PWD_DIR=$(pwd)
SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"
cd ${SCRIPT_DIR}
cd ..

SERVER_COMPONENT=$1
export ENVIRONMENT_NAME=$2
if [ ! -f docker-compose.${SERVER_COMPONENT}."${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}".yml ]; then
    ENVIRONMENT_FILE=""
else
    ENVIRONMENT_FILE="-f docker-compose.${SERVER_COMPONENT}."${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}".yml"
fi
if [ ! -f docker-compose.media."${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}".yml ]; then
    MEDIA_ENVIRONMENT_FILE=""
else
    MEDIA_ENVIRONMENT_FILE="-f docker-compose.media."${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}".yml"
fi

docker-compose -f docker-compose.media.yml ${MEDIA_ENVIRONMENT_FILE} -f docker-compose.database.yml ${ENVIRONMENT_FILE} exec mongo mongod --shutdown
docker-compose -f docker-compose.media.yml ${MEDIA_ENVIRONMENT_FILE} -f docker-compose.database.yml ${ENVIRONMENT_FILE} exec rabbitmq rabbitmqctl shutdown
docker-compose -f docker-compose.media.yml ${MEDIA_ENVIRONMENT_FILE} -f docker-compose.database.yml ${ENVIRONMENT_FILE} exec -u postgres postgres pg_ctl stop
docker-compose -f docker-compose.media.yml ${MEDIA_ENVIRONMENT_FILE} -f docker-compose.database.yml ${ENVIRONMENT_FILE} stop

cd ${PWD_DIR}
```